Calculating Expected Value of 1/(S+1) for a Poisson Binomial Random Variable
Let $S$ be a Poisson Binomial random variable, i.e. the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables with parameters $p_1, ..., p_n$. I'd like to know the expected value of $\frac{1}{1+S}$, hopefully as some nice sum or product involving the $p_i$'s. I thought I had something but I've gotten stuck. Here's what I've got.
We want $E[\frac{1}{1+S}]=\sum_{i=0}^nP(S=s)\frac{1}{1+s}$. Now note that $\frac{1}{1+s}=\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+s)}dt$, and so we get $$E[\frac{1}{1+S}]=\sum_{i=0}^nP(S=s)\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+s)}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}E[e^{-tS}]dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}M(-t)dt,$$ where $$M(t)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i + e^t p_i)$$ is the moment generating function for $S$.
I thought this looked somewhat promising, but I've gotten quite stuck trying to find a closed form for this integral. I have verified numerically that everything I have so far is correct.
Any ideas?
Edited to add
I carried on down the road that I started describing above and found sort of an interesting identity but not a particularly helpful one, I don't think. For the sake of posterity and to prevent others from going down my same rabbit hole, here's the dead end where it leads.
I actually use that $$E\left[\frac{1}{k+S}\right]=\int_0 ^\infty e^{-kt}M(-t)dt$$ which is basically derived the same way as above. Now also note that $$M'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n e^tp_i\prod _{j\ne i}(1-p_j + e^tp_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n e^tp_iM_{-i}(t)$$ where $M_{-i}$ is the moment generating function for a Poisson Binomial variable $S_{-i}$, $S$ without the $i$th term. That's kind of neat. Now, integrating $E\left[\frac{1}{k+S}\right]=\int_0 ^\infty e^{-kt}M(-t)dt$ by parts gives: $$
\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{1}{k+S}\right] &= \int_0 ^\infty e^{-kt}M(-t)dt \\
&= \left[-\frac{1}{k}e^{-kt}M(-t) \right]_0^\infty - \frac{1}{k}\int_0^\infty \sum_{i=1}^n p_ie^{-(k+1)t}M_{-i}(-t)dt \\
&= \frac{1}{k}\left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^n p_i E\left[\frac{1}{k+1+S_{-i}}\right]\right)
\end{align}
$$
Now, starting from $k=1$ and expanding the terms recursively gives the following sum.
$$
\begin{align}
E\left[ \frac{1}{1+S} \right] &= 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n p_i E\left[\frac{1}{2+S_{-i}}\right] \\
  &= 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \sum_{j\ne i} p_j E\left[\frac{1}{3+S_{-i}}\right] \right) \\
  &= 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \frac{1}{2}
\left(1 - \sum_{j\ne i} p_j \frac{1}{3}
\left(1 - \sum_{k\notin \{i,j\}} p_j
E\left[\frac{1}{4+S_{-i}}\right]
\right)
\right) \\
  &= \dots
\end{align}
$$
I thought this looked quite promising and interesting. Rearranging and simplifying, I finally got to the following place.
$$
E\left[\frac{1}{1+S}\right] = \sum_{s=0}^n \frac{(-1)^s}{(s+1)} \sum_{|F|=s}\prod_{i \in F} p_i
$$
Sadly... this is no simpler or easier to compute than just evaluating the PMF directly, I don't think, and I also suspect there's probably a much easier way to derive this identity as it seems related to applying the inclusion-exclusion principle. So, a bunch of work for nothing it seems. But it was fun.

Maybe the Fourier transform can help.
See "Hong, Y. On computing the distribution function for the poisson binomial distribution. Computational Statistics & Data Analysis, 59:41–51, 2013."

I feel the best we can get is just
$$\sum_{S \subseteq [n]} \prod_{i \in S} p_i \prod_{j \notin S} (1-p_j) \frac{1}{1 +|S|}$$
Are you expecting some nicer closed form than this?

I agree. But why on earth did you choose the letter $S$  for your index of summation?

I was hoping for something nicer, yes. That sum could have millions of terms. But maybe it’s the best we can get.

I do find that numerically evaluating that integral is better than trying to do that sum, since it only involves a product of $n$ terms instead of $|[n]|$ terms. But I was hoping for a closed form.

If $p_i$'s are not arbitrary but take the form $p_i=f(i/n)$ for some function $f(x)$, then I guess we might possibly approximate the expectation by a more tractable expression in terms of $f$.

If $Y \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ then $$E\left[\frac{1}{1+Y}\right] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{1+k}\right)\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda} = \frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}$$ which could be a good approximation of the expectation of the actual random variable $S$ when $n$ is large (and perhaps when $p_i = O(1/n)$).
